# What was the first historical use of polynomials?

Tags: polynomials, math-history

From Taylor series to polynomial regression to physics, polynomial functions are ubiquitous in [daily use](https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-real-life-applications-of-polynomials/answer/Praveen-Kamath-7?share=a559f6f4&srid=utSnl).

But they also seem to date back to [Babylonian times](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/a/2505).

> The question is, What were the first practical applications of polynomials that justified their widespread use? Or were they initially the fruit of pure mathematical exploration (e.g. conic sections)?

Comment: This question is better for [History of Science and Mathematics](https://hsm.stackexchange.com). Moreover, the answer of Alexandre Eremenko also contains some good points for this question.

Comment: Why do you think that the theory of conic sections would be of purely mathematical interest to ancient people trying to understand astronomical phenomena?

Comment: @RobArthan What is implied in your question, that the first use was trying to understand astronomical phenomena, or that it wasn't conic sections that started the use of polynomials? I certainly don't have the answer; my question was not rhetorical. So if you are hinting at something, please make it explicit.

Comment: @DietrichBurde It was with the object of preempting your comment that I linked the OP to the question in the history of science. Please note that 1. There is **math-history tag** within Math SE. And 2. That the post linked to, albeit containing excellent answers, doesn't get into the actual technical issues that initially triggered the development of polynomials.

Comment: At least with respect to the Babylonian civilization, it seems that initially the use of polynomials was not related to practical applications. According to [Kleiner's book](https://books.google.com.br/books/about/A_History_of_Abstract_Algebra.html?id=udj-1UuaOiIC&source=kp_cover&redir_esc=y): *The Babylonians were able to solve quadratic equations, as well as equations that lead to quadratic equations. The problems were often phrased in geometric language, but they were not problems in geometry. Nor were they of practical use; they were likely intended for the training of students.*

Comment: I just meant that the conic sections that are visible in nature must have been of interest to the ancients, while your remark in brackets suggests that you think they were of purely mathematical interest.